# Running remote commands, with local arguments, through socat?

Tags: linux, unix, tcp, socat

I would like to set up a socat socket on Computer A, which will receive a string from a socket on Computer B. This string should be interpreted as arguments to a command that will be executed on Computer A, e.g.:

Computer A:

`socat TCP4-L:3334,fork SYSTEM:"./parsecommand.sh $INCOMING_STRING_OF_ARGS"`

Computer B:

`socat TCP4:remote.host:3334 SYSTEM:"echo 'out going string of args'"`

Is this the correct syntax for such a motion? E.g., is there some variable equivalent to $@ in the socat universe, so that I can replace $INCOMING_STRING_OF_ARGS with that variable to make this work?

In full context: what we want is a 'socat' replacement of running remote commands with 'ssh'. We want to establish a bi-directional connection between Computer A and Computer B, send commands from Computer B to Computer A, execute the commands on Computer A, and return the output to Computer B.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're looking for a reverse shell?

On server:

```
$ socat tcp-l:5050,reuseaddr,fork system:bash
```

(Add transport security with `openssl-l` instead of `tcp-listen`.)

On client:

```
$ socat - tcp:<server-ip>:5050
```

Or simply `netcat`:

```
$ nc <server-ip> 5050
```

Or if you want your shell script to handle the incoming commands:

```bash
$ cat parsecommand.sh
#!/bin/bash
#
# WARNING: command injection possible: don't use on production
while read -r remote_cmd; do
    case "$remote_cmd" in
        ls*) bash -c "$remote_cmd";;
        *) ;;
    esac
done
```

This is all terribly insecure, so I would recommend sticking with SSH.